# How to map Entities and Domain Model when removing things

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

As far as I understand, the domain model should not know about the persistence layer. But then... How can I deal with removing element that are dependant of a father object?

For example, in my domain, if I have a ShoppingBasket with Products, and I want to remove a Product. I can remove the Product in my Domain Model. But how will I get my persistence layer to be aware that a Product must be deleted (i.e. how do I get the corresponding product relashionship removed from the database)?

Comment: Are you using an ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate (or Hibernate for Java)? If so, then @RobertHarvey's answer is appropriate. If you are creating your own data access code, then you've got some additional work.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt yes, i had an ORM in mind. It happens to be Doctrine, but the same applies.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in situations like this, there is an object that maps the associated objects to each other.  In this case, it would be a `BasketItem` object.  It would look something like this:

```
public class BasketItem
{
    public int BasketID;
    public int ProductID;
    public int Quantity;
}
```

Removal of the item from the basket is a simple matter of removing the appropriate `BasketItem` object.

This is basic database design, which is why it's not obvious.  Database design is not always taught in "class first" paradigms, which is unfortunate.

Comment: It appears the OP's target language is PHP, given that he had the Doctrine ORM in mind. Same advice applies, though.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: How did you figure that out from the question text?

Comment: It was in a comment to his question. It really should be included in the question text.